# 10054 error on connecting to winsock

Tags: c++, https, winsock

I am trying to establish a secured (https) connection. In my sample code, I am trying to connect to www.yahoo.com on port 443. 
Although the connection is established and I am able to send a HTTP CONNECT request, the response from the server is winsock error 10054.
I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
// HttpsTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <WinSock2.h>

#define BUFFFER_SIZE    1024*1024
#define MESSAGE "CONNECT www.yahoo.com:443 HTTP/1.0\
User - Agent : Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident / 7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko\
Host : www.yahoo.com\
    Content - Length : 0\
    DNT : 1\
    Proxy - Connection : Keep - Alive\
     Pragma : no - cache"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2); //0x202

    int wsaError = ::WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

    char *pBuffer = MESSAGE;

    string server_name("www.yahoo.com");
    int retval, Len;
    unsigned int addr;
    int socket_type = SOCK_STREAM;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct hostent *hp = NULL;
    DWORD dwPort = 443;

    hp = gethostbyname(server_name.c_str());
    if (hp == NULL)
    {
        wsaError = ::WSAGetLastError();
    }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    memcpy(&(server.sin_addr), hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    server.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    server.sin_port = htons(static_cast<u_short>(dwPort));

    SOCKET connToServer = socket(AF_INET, socket_type, IPPROTO_TCP); /* Open a socket */
    if (connToServer != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        if (connect(connToServer, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            wsaError = ::WSAGetLastError();
        }
    }
    Len = strlen(pBuffer);
    retval = send(connToServer, pBuffer, Len, 0);
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wsaError = ::WSAGetLastError();
    }
    vector<char> vecBuffer(BUFFFER_SIZE, 0);
    retval = recv(connToServer, vecBuffer.data(), static_cast<int>(vecBuffer.capacity()) - 1, 0);
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wsaError = ::WSAGetLastError(); // Always get a 10054.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you want to establish connection with **encrypted** protocol why do you expect server to respond to non encrypted request?

Comment: Is that what I am doing? Should I not be using recv at all? This code works with http and I was trying to check what to do with https

Comment: do you really think that you send the same text data but through different port and it becomes secured? Did you read description of https protocol - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure ?

Comment: All I was attempting was to provide tunnelling by extending an existing proxy. I think I might've already figured out what's wrong. Thanks for the help